# How can I install GLEW without Visual Studio?

Tags: cmake, mingw, glew

I require the use of [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) to build a project.

I'm doing this using a makefile in CMake, and MinGW as the compiler.

The makefile contains this code:

```
find_package (GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories ("${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_link_libraries (game ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

The instructions on the [GLEW site](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) indicate an approach that requires the usage of Visual Studio which I do not want to use. How can I install GLEW / otherwise include GLEW in such a way that fulfills the makefile's utter GLEW-depravation, without requiring the use of Visual Studio?

Comment: "MinGW Makefiles" as generator is your answer

Comment: There are many ways to do so. You should maybe precise how you would compile your project ? With the help of an IDE, or mingw makefile ?

Comment: I am using a MinGW makefile, but I think I am using CMake to generate this makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can download pre-build libraries for Windows:

> Pre-built shared and static libraries are also available for [download](http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html).